# Visualize implication chain in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

What I would like is a prolog program where I list a bunch of if-thens (so a ton of rules). As a result, I would like to see a graph of implications as a result of one of the rules. So if a() leads to 50 other things through a bunch of rules, I would like to see all of the things it leads to, and the path it took to get there. Maybe something like this:

```
?- (something here...) :- studyBiology(X)

studyBiology(X)
    goToMedicalSchool(X)
        becomeADoctor(X)
    learnToHateBiology(X)
        startARockBand(X)
```

Similarly, I would like to name some predicate, and see all of the ways to get there, and the paths leading up to it:

```
?- beSuccessful(X) :- (something here...).

beSuccessful()
    goToCollege()
        getGoodGradesInSchool()
    runAnEthicalBusiness(), haveAGreatMarketingTeam()
        dropOutAndStartABusiness()
```

Is this possible in Prolog? Or should I build something custom that does this in another language?

Comment: Anything is possible. How elaborate it is will depend upon your detailed requirements. Each rule could do a `write('rule x'), nl` to standard output when it succeeds. If you need each level to indent the output, you might need to carry along an *depth* variable (representing how deep you are in rule calls) that you can use to determine indent level. This is more than just putting *something here* in your `(something here...) :- studyBiology(X)`.

Comment: I have rules like `b(X) :- a(X)`, `b(X) :- c(X)`, but when I try the query `b(X)`, there is an error. I think this is because I don't have any facts stating that something has the property a, b, or c. I would like to be able to see everything that causes b. How can I do that?

Comment: If you are looking for an execution trace, you can use `trace`. You can also trace a specific predicate, `trace(b)`. But there isn't a pre-built tool within Prolog that analyzes the code statically.